# Switch between two attached displays

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I have a desktop monitor and a tv which I would both like to attach to my pc.
The desktop monitor is attached with a displayport cable, while the tv is attached with a hdmi cable.

Is there an easy "switch" program, to select what monitor should be used?
I know I can buy an hdmi switcher or something like that, but a software solution would be nice.

I never want to use both monitors at the same time, only on at the time.

Maybe relevant information:
The tv and the monitor are different resolutions (4k vs 2560x1080)
The graphics card is a nVidia 960.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Windows:
pressing <kbd>Win + P</kbd> brings up the monitor swapping feature built into Windows.

Select:
`Show Desktop on monitor 1`
or
`Show Desktop on monitor 2`

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select.

Comment: Did not knew this was possible on desktop computers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same environment and switch manually in the nVidia Panel (I just de-select the monitor which I dont want to use). However, I dont know if there is better software to switch easier. Sorry.